# Get link from wpe_excerpt "read more" and move it

Tags: permalinks, excerpt

I apologize in advance, I'm no wordpress developer, and am having a difficult time transitioning to cms dev from organic dev, so sorry if this is a simple question or has been asked in different words before.

Here's my question, I'm editing a page that echoes out excerpts via `wpe_excerpt` including the `read more` link. What I'd like to do is take that link and make the entire container for the excerpt and make it link to the content in question.

Of course I know how to make the container link to the content, but how do I get that link?

Thanks!

Comment: I think, wpe_excerpt misspelled. Its "the_excerpt".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested in fetching the post's link. [get_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) and [the_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) are the functions that returns the URL of current post, if that is what you want.

Comment: Awesome, `<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">` worked, now I just have to fix the styles that having a link wrapping content created. Thanks! I'd upvote but it's my first post on WPSE, I'll make sure to come back in a couple weeks and up vote, thanks!